# Installing uberSVN on a server with an existing Apache server

Tags: apache, svn, ubersvn

I'm installing uberSVN on an Ubuntu server with an existing Apache installation. Rather than using uberSVN's built-in Apache server on a different port to access the SVN repositories, I'd like to use a vhost on the currently running one.

Are there any ways I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As uberSVN is meant to be able to run 'out of the box' it will use it's own instance of Apache even if you have another one already installed. This is not something configurable (at least not from the UI), and is not recommended to be changed as it can cause problems if there are different uses or port conflicts. Is there a specific reason that using uberSVN's instance is an issue?